# Check seriescollection formula in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I would like to check if `seriescollection(1).formula` is of expected string or .value of expected range, but anything I try always succeeds regardless of data like:

```
If graf.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = _ 
       Range("Podatki!$B$1:$C$97;Podatki!$K$1:$L$97") Then
            MsgBox ("1")
End If

If graf.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _ 
       Range("Podatki!$B$1:$C$97;Podatki!$K$1:$L$97") Then
            MsgBox ("2")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing the `Formula` statement in this row (first row):

```
graf.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = Range("Podatki!$B$1:$C$97;Podatki!$K$1:$L$97") .Formula
```

Similarly for `values`:

```
graf.SeriesCollection(1).Value2 = Range("Podatki!$B$1:$C$97;Podatki!$K$1:$L$97").Value2
```

Comment: How to close question on android?